# MailChimp Campaign Hourly Stats taking up too much data in the Storage Usage

Tags: campaign, mail-chimp

I am having an issue of `MailChimp Campaign Hourly Stats` taking up too much data in my Salesforce environment. 
When I open my Salforce Storage Usage nearly all of my storage data is taken from `MailChimp Campaign Hourly Stats`.
I need to know what exactly are the `MailChimp Campaign Hourly Stats`?
Is each `MailChimp Campaign Hourly Stats` activity a record or is it some other type? 
And where do I find that in reports in order to create a list of the id's to delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete this data with the [Apex Data Loader](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/15/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf). Start with an Export, find the MailChimp Campaign Hourly Stats, export all the rows, and then run the export file through the Delete option.

To prevent further data from being generated, go to the MailChimp Settings tab/app, and turn off the Campaign Hourly Sync function. This will suppress the these records, which are basically just logs that you should enable only if/when you're trying to figure out why records are not being updated.